# Is there a way to send back a string as well as an image via Http response?

Tags: http, servlets, httprequest, httpresponse

I am hitting a servlet and based on the data passed to the server , I have two conditions.

1) If data is 'X' then I have to return a string in response.
2) If data is 'Y' then I have to return a string as well an image in response.

So is this scenario possible? How do I return both a string as well as image from the server?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Simply return the URL of the image and store it in the session object, something like this:

```
String imgUrl = "...URL";
request.getSession.setAttribute("Image", imgUrl);
```

Then call the requestDispatcher and forward it to a jsp, so

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/myJsp").forward(req, resp);
```

Then, from the JSP extract the imgUrl,

```
<% String url = (String)session.getSession.getAttribute("Image");
```

and there you go.

Good luck!